# How to upload image manually using cdeditor in php?

Tags: ckeditor, rich-text-editor, ckeditor5

This is my start up code,when i click on image button the image is not adding to the editable place can anyone say how to build own image adaptor in php with some customn options???

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>CKEditor 5 – Document editor</title>
  <script src="https://cdn.ckeditor.com/ckeditor5/30.0.0/decoupled-document/ckeditor.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>Document editor</h1>

  <!-- The toolbar will be rendered in this container. -->
  <div id="toolbar-container"></div>

  <!-- This container will become the editable. -->
  <div id="editor">
    <p>This is the initial editor content.</p>
  </div>

  <script>
    DecoupledEditor
      .create(document.querySelector('#editor'))
      .then(editor => {
        const toolbarContainer = document.querySelector('#toolbar-container');

        toolbarContainer.appendChild(editor.ui.view.toolbar.element);
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.error(error);
      });
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```